# OpenGL ES 1.1 to 2.0 a major change?

Tags: xcode, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

I'm creating an iPhone app with cocos2d and I'm trying to make use of the following OpenGL ES 1.1 code. However, I'm not good with OpenGL and my app makes use of OpenGL ES 2.0 so I need to convert it.

Thus I was wondering, how difficult would it be to convert the following code from ES 1.1 to ES 2.0? Is there some source that could tell me which methods need replacing etc?

```
-(void) draw
{
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glColor4ub(_color.r, _color.g, _color.b, _opacity);
    glLineWidth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    //non-GL code here

    if (_opacity != 255)
        glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);

    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about ES or desktop here? Makes a huge difference. In the former case (reomve the opengl tag) it won't be that easy. In the latter case (remove the es tags) there shouldn't be any proting problems.

Comment: Ah yes, must have overread that. In this case porting won't be that easy and you need to get into GLSL shaders.

Comment: O god... this effect literally took me a few minutes to implement in Flash :/ thanks for the advice, I'll probs have to look at alternative methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It will not be that easy if you're not so fit in OpenGL.

OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't have a fixed-function pipeline anymore. This means you have to manage vertex transformations, lighting, texturing and the like all yourself using GLSL vertex and fragment shaders. You also have to keep track of the transformation matrices yourself, there are no `glMatrixMode`, `glPushMatrix`, `glTranslate`, ... anymore.

There are also no buitlin vertex attributes anymore (like `glVertex`, `glColor`, ...). So these functions, along with the corresponding array functions (like `glVertexPointer`, `glColorPointer`, ...) and `gl(En/Dis)ableClientState`, have been reomved, too. Instead you need the generic vertex attribute functions (`glVertexAttrib`, `glVertexAttribPointer` and `gl(En/Dis)ableVertexAttribArray`, which behave similarly) together with a corresponding vertex shader to give these attributes their correct meaning.

I suggest you look into a good OpenGL ES 2.0 tutorial or book, as porting from 1.1 to 2.0 is really a major change, at least if you never have heard anything about shaders.

Comment: Well put thanks, I might try 2.0 from scratch. I understand 2.0 gives more possibilities, but couldn't they ALSO give the shortcuts of 1.1? I find it unbelievable that they sat that and thought "I know, in version 2.0 we'll take out everything and let people do it all themselves". I don't mind taking time to learn some low-level things but looking at some tutorials it takes them about an hour to make a rotating cube. I'm suprised for simple line drawing etc someone hasn't come in with something better.

Comment: @user666254 You are indeed right that setting up simple things requires more effort now and it is also harder to learn for beginners, as you cannot do much without understanding the whole API and pipeline. But on the other hand it is now much harder to do things the wrong way (like `glBegin/glEnd`, ...) and the API is much cleaner. And you won't find any serious application not using shaders anyway (maybe today, but surely not tomorrow).

Comment: @user666254 Something better? A new hardware-accelerated API hardware vendors have to support, that achieves a subset of the possibilities already existing? Not very likely to happen. For simple things you can still use OpenGL ES 1.1, of course. But somewhere has to be made an advancement into the future.