# Box2D Drawing Is Off By A Factor of 2 With cocos2d-iphone version 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d

After upgrading to cocos2d-iphone version 2.0, I am having problems with the coordinates that objects are being drawn. To the best of my knowledge, I have upgraded all of the templates correctly, but there is still a problem. For example, in the "Learning Cocos2D" book (chapter 10 on box2D), I have implemented a couple simple methods to first createGround and to createBoxAtLocation. The first method is called from init and is as follows:

```
- (void)createGround {
    CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];     

    // Set up the Box2D coordinates that correspond to the four corners of the ground boundary
    float32 margin = 10.0f;
    b2Vec2 lowerLeft = b2Vec2(margin/PTM_RATIO, margin/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Vec2 lowerRight = b2Vec2((winSize.width-margin)/PTM_RATIO, margin/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Vec2 upperRight = b2Vec2((winSize.width-margin)/PTM_RATIO,
                           (winSize.height-margin)/PTM_RATIO);
    b2Vec2 upperLeft = b2Vec2(margin/PTM_RATIO,
                          (winSize.height-margin)/PTM_RATIO);
    // Define the static container body, which will provide the collisions at screen borders.
    b2BodyDef screenBorderDef;
    screenBorderDef.position.Set(0, 0);
    b2Body* screenBorderBody = world->CreateBody(&screenBorderDef);
    b2EdgeShape screenBorderShape;

    // Create fixtures for the four borders (the border shape is re-used)
    screenBorderShape.Set(lowerLeft, lowerRight);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(lowerRight, upperRight);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(upperRight, upperLeft);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
    screenBorderShape.Set(upperLeft, lowerLeft);
    screenBorderBody->CreateFixture(&screenBorderShape, 0);
}
```

This is supposed to draw a green boundary around the edge of the screen with a 10 point margin. However, I can only see the green boundary on the bottom and left edge. The top edge and right edge are drawn at 2X the screen height and width respectively.

Within the same Box2D example, a box is to be drawn at the point that the user touches the screen. When the user touches the screen, the method createBoxAtLocation is called with the location of the touch. The touch location coordinates are in cocos2d point coordinates and are within the range that you would expect them to be. Below is the method createBoxAtLocation:

```
- (void)createBoxAtLocation:(CGPoint)location
               withSize:(CGSize)size
{

    // First create a body
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;                      // This box is a dynamic body (movement handled by box2d)
    bodyDef.position = b2Vec2(location.x/PTM_RATIO,     // convert the point location to meters location
                          location.y/PTM_RATIO);
    bodyDef.allowSleep = false;
    b2Body *body = world->CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    // Now create one or more fixtures to add to the body.
    // To do this, you must first create a shape. In this case, we are creating a square box
    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.SetAsBox(size.width/2/PTM_RATIO, size.height/2/PTM_RATIO);    // SetAsBox takes half dimensions as parameters

    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = 1.0;           // set density. The higher the number, the heavier it is

    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
}
```

For example, if the touch location was the point coordinates of 193, 190.5 (on a iphone retina display), the method createBoxAtLocation will draw a box at point coordinates of 386, 381 even though the location.x = 193 and the location.y = 190.5. Note that bodyDef.position has box2d coordinates of 3.86, 3.81 because PTM_RATIO is 50.

I can also say that when I run the simulator and select the iphone (non-retina) as the hardware, the box is created at the proper location and createGround produces the proper boundary within the screen space. I can also say that the code recognizes the proper size screen for all devices (e.g. cocos2d prints out cocos2d: surface size: 480x320 for iphone and cocos2d: surface size: 960x640 for iphone 3.5 retina). Finally, I have run the debugger and burrowed down into the drawing routines. As far as I can tell and comprehend, the proper box2d coordinates are known by the drawing routine. But the box is just getting displayed at a coordinate that is 2X what it should be for retina displays.

I suspect that both the problem with createGround and the problem with createBoxAtLocation are the same. I am certain there is a simple solution to this, but I cannot figure it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: I am thinking that this might have something to do with OpenGL ES 2.0 as I believe that cocos2d uses this instead of OpenGL ES 1.1. In particular, I think this is a problem with setupDebugDraw which utilizes an override of the draw method. This draw method provided by "Learning Cocos2D" utilizes some deprecated/undefined GL methods. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777605/opengl-es-1-1-to-2-0-a-major-change, these are not easily fixed. See next comment for continuation:

Comment: In the cocos2d forum topic (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/21311), "the new version of GLES-DebugDraw class constructor does not accept PTM_RATIO parameter anymore." This person says they "haven't found a way to set PTM_RATIO so the debug drawings are not correctly scaled."  Furthermore, if I continue on with the box2d example in chapter 10 where the debugDraw is no longer used, then the example code works as expected. In other words, using debugDraw is not possible, but using the normal draw seems to work ok.